# How can you activate a conda environment through a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, conda

Through the terminal, it's as simple as `source activate MyCondaEnv`, but if I try in a Jenkinsfile:

```
sh '. /home/rwardrup/anaconda3/bin/activate MyCondaEnv',
```

The Jenkins console returns:

```
Running shell script
+ . /home/rwardrup/anaconda3/bin/activate MyCondaEnv
+ [[ -n ]]
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/features@tmp/durable-bb4a4c30/script.sh: 4: /home/rwardrup/anaconda3/bin/activate: [[: not found
+ [[ -n ]]
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/features@tmp/durable-bb4a4c30/script.sh: 7: /home/rwardrup/anaconda3/bin/activate: [[: not found
+ echo Only bash and zsh are supported
Only bash and zsh are supported
+ return 1
```

I've tried throwing a little shebang in there: `sh '$!/bin/bash. /home/rwardrup/anaconda3/bin/activate MyCondaEnv'`, thinking that it could have to do with that, and I get:

```
Running shell script
+ /bin/bash. /home/rwardrup/anaconda3/bin/activate MyCondaEnv
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/features@tmp/durable-2a550d19/script.sh: 2: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/features@tmp/durable-2a550d19/script.sh: /bin/bash.: not found
```

Is there any way to activate and use a Conda environment through a Jenkinsfile? I've found some info on using a [Django venv in a Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450159/how-can-i-write-a-groovy-jenkinsfile-for-a-django-application-to-run-my-tests), but that didn't work in my situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like an incorrect syntax for shebang and a missng newline after.

Try this:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
     . /home/rwardrup/anaconda3/bin/activate MyCondaEnv
'''
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much.